# UIViewController title can't be "Message"?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

This is a weird question. Whenever I set UIViewController title to "Message", the text disappeared. Is there any way to fix it?

```
self.title = @"Message";
```

Comment: Are you saying that if you set it to `@MessageX"` it works? Or do you mean if you set it to any value, it disappears?

Comment: Yes I set to @"MessageX" it works.

Comment: Well, I change set to @"Message "(with a white space at the end) and it displayed. But is "Message" a reserved title or something?

Comment: I just changed on of my view controllers to have a title of `@"Message"` and it works just fine. You need to provide more details. Where do you set the title? What is your setup? Is this all in code? Is the navbar displayed but just no title?

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. Xcode 5.1, deployment target iOS 7.1, iPad simulator. Please give some more specifics. If you could attach a link to a zipped project that would be good.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an issue with particular title "Message", it's displaying successfully **[tested]**

Just make sure that you are not changing it anywhere.

```
self.title = @"";
```

Or may be you are adding other view over your title.

You can try this one also.

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"";
```